# Perceptron algorithm

Tags: java, homework, machine-learning

This is the Perceptron algorithm, I wrote this implementation with my friend. It gets the job done, but it's quite dirty, perhaps one of you stylish hackers might help me beautify this beast.

This is what I made to generate my data structures and run everything:

```
public class FileDictCreateur 
{
    static String PATH = "/home/yamada/Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/practice_data/data/train";

    //the global list of all words across all articles
    static Set<String> GLOBO_DICT = new HashSet<String>();

    //is the globo dict full?
    static boolean globo_dict_fixed = false;

    // hash map of all the words contained in individual files
    static Map<File, ArrayList<String> > training_fileDict = new HashMap<>();

    static Map<File, ArrayList<String> > test_fileDict = new HashMap<>();

    //input to perceptron. final struc.
    static Map<File, int[] > training_perceptron_input = new HashMap<>();

    static Map<File, int[] > test_perceptron_input = new HashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        //each of the diferent categories
        String[] categories = { "/atheism", "/politics", "/science", "/sports"};

        //cycle through all categories once to populate the global dict
        for(int cycle = 0; cycle <= 3; cycle++)
        {
            String general_data_partition = PATH + categories[cycle];

            File directory = new File( general_data_partition );
            iterateDirectory( directory , globo_dict_fixed, training_fileDict ); //that training dict doesn't need to be here
            // ^ NEEDS REFACTORING!!!

            if(cycle == 3)
                globo_dict_fixed = true;
        }


        //cycle through again to populate the file dicts
        for(int cycle = 0; cycle <= 3; cycle++)
        {
            String general_data_partition = PATH + categories[cycle];

            File directory = new File( general_data_partition );
            iterateDirectory( directory , globo_dict_fixed, training_fileDict );

        }

        //get feature vectors for the training data
        perceptron_data_struc_generateur( GLOBO_DICT, training_fileDict, training_perceptron_input );





        //cycle through all categories once to populate the global dict
        for(int cycle = 0; cycle <= 3; cycle++)
        {
            //get the test data
            String test_path = "/home/yamada/Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/practice_data/data/test";
            File test_dict = new File( test_path + categories[cycle]);
            iterateDirectory( test_dict , globo_dict_fixed, test_fileDict );
        }

        //get feature vectors for the TEST data
        perceptron_data_struc_generateur( GLOBO_DICT, test_fileDict, test_perceptron_input );




        for (Map.Entry<File, int[]> entry : test_perceptron_input.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
        }



        ///AHHAHAHAHH!!!!!!
        Perceptron.perceptron( GLOBO_DICT, training_perceptron_input, test_perceptron_input );





    }



    private static void iterateDirectory(File directory, boolean globo_dict_fixed, Map<File, ArrayList<String> > fileDict ) throws IOException 
    {
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) 
        {
            if (file.isDirectory()) 
            {
                iterateDirectory(directory, globo_dict_fixed, fileDict );
            } 
            else 
            {   
                String line; 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file ));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your words

                    if(globo_dict_fixed == false)
                    {
                        populate_globo_dict( words );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        create_file_dict( file, words, fileDict );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void create_file_dict( File file, String[] words, Map<File, ArrayList<String> > fileDict ) throws IOException
    {   

        if (!fileDict.containsKey(file))
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ArrayList document_words = new ArrayList<String>();

            String word;

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
            {
                word = words[i];

                document_words.add(word);
            }
            fileDict.put(file, document_words);
        }
    }

    public static void populate_globo_dict( String[] words ) throws IOException
    {
        String word;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
        {
            word = words[i];
            if (!GLOBO_DICT.contains(word))
            {
                GLOBO_DICT.add(word);
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void perceptron_data_struc_generateur(Set<String> GLOBO_DICT, 
                                                        Map<File, ArrayList<String> > fileDict,
                                                        Map<File, int[] > perceptron_input)
    {
        //create a new entry in the array list 'perceptron_input'
        //with the key as the file name from fileDict
            //create a new array which is the length of GLOBO_DICT
            //iterate through the indicies of GLOBO_DICT
                //for all words in globo dict, if that word appears in fileDict,
                //increment the perceptron_input index that corresponds to that
                //word in GLOBO_DICT by the number of times that word appears in fileDict

        //so i can get the index later
        List<String> GLOBO_DICT_list = new ArrayList<>(GLOBO_DICT);

        for (Map.Entry<File, ArrayList<String>> entry : fileDict.entrySet()) 
        {
            int[] cross_czech = new int[GLOBO_DICT_list.size()];
            //initialize to zero
            Arrays.fill(cross_czech, 0);

            for (String s : GLOBO_DICT_list)
            {

                for(String st : entry.getValue()) 
                {
                    if( st.equals(s) )
                    {
                        cross_czech[ GLOBO_DICT_list.indexOf( s ) ] = cross_czech[ GLOBO_DICT_list.indexOf( s ) ] +1;
                    }
                }
            }
            perceptron_input.put( entry.getKey() , cross_czech);    
        }
    }
}
```

I was having a lot of trouble trying to implement the perceptron algorithm, but then I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aksMtJHWEQ), it goes through a java implementation and then has some example code. I substituted my own data structures for there ones in the tutorial, and it works! :)

**HOWEVER**

I made this substitution in the most simplistic possible way, manually enumerating my data structures. This works as a proof of concept, for my experimental "toy" data, but most certainly is not able to tackle the real data I want to consider. It's far too rigid.

Perhaps someone more proficient in abstract thinking and loops would be able to show me how I can improve this code.

The important data structure to consider is `Map<File, int[] >`, it looks like this:

```
/data/test/sports/t.s_1.txt, [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
/data/test/politics/t.p_0.txt, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
/data/test/atheism/t.a_0.txt, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
/data/test/science/t.s_0.txt, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

The code above needs to be generalized.  You can also find the full programme on [GitHub](https://github.com/h1395010/perceptron/tree/dadea91e2613cbe9f5284dfdb661d53764dff463).

```
public static void perceptron( Set<String> GLOBO_DICT, Map<File, int[] > training_perceptron_input, Map<File, int[] > test_perceptron_input)
  {

         //number of features, number of x, y, z
         int size_of_globo_dict = GLOBO_DICT.size();

         //number of instances
         int NUM_INSTANCES = training_perceptron_input.size();


            //three variables (features) they enumerate by
            //features, xyz, i also do that
            double[] a00 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a01 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a02 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];    
            double[] a03 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a04 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a05 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a06 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a07 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a08 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a09 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a10 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a11 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a12 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a13 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a14 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a15 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a16 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a17 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a18 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a19 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a20 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a21 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a22 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a23 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a24 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a25 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a26 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a27 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a28 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a29 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
            double[] a30 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];


    //2d array for features
    int x = 0;
    int[][] feature_matrix = new int[ training_perceptron_input.size() ][ GLOBO_DICT.size() ];
    String[][] output_label = new String[ training_perceptron_input.size() ][ 2 ];

    for(Entry<File, int[]> entry : training_perceptron_input.entrySet())
    {
        int[] container =entry.getValue();

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            feature_matrix[x][j] = container[j];

            output_label[x][1] = entry.getKey().toString(); 
        }
            x++;
    }



    int[] outputs = new int [NUM_INSTANCES];

    for(int g = 0; g < NUM_INSTANCES; g++)
    {
        a00[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 0];
        a01[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 1];
        a02[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 2];
        a03[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 3];
        a04[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 4];
        a05[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 5];
        a06[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 6];
        a07[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 7];
        a08[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 8];
        a09[g] = feature_matrix[g][ 9];
        a10[g] = feature_matrix[g][10];
        a11[g] = feature_matrix[g][11];
        a12[g] = feature_matrix[g][12];
        a13[g] = feature_matrix[g][13];
        a14[g] = feature_matrix[g][14];
        a15[g] = feature_matrix[g][15];
        a16[g] = feature_matrix[g][16];
        a17[g] = feature_matrix[g][17];
        a18[g] = feature_matrix[g][18];
        a19[g] = feature_matrix[g][19];
        a20[g] = feature_matrix[g][20];
        a21[g] = feature_matrix[g][21];
        a22[g] = feature_matrix[g][22];
        a23[g] = feature_matrix[g][23];
        a24[g] = feature_matrix[g][24];
        a25[g] = feature_matrix[g][25];
        a26[g] = feature_matrix[g][26];
        a27[g] = feature_matrix[g][27];
        a28[g] = feature_matrix[g][28];
        a29[g] = feature_matrix[g][29];
        a30[g] = feature_matrix[g][30];
        if(output_label[g][1].equals( "/home/yamada/Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/practice_data/data/train/atheism/a_0.txt" ) )
        {
            outputs[g] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            outputs[g] = 0;
        }
    }


    double[] weights = new double[ GLOBO_DICT.size() + 1];// 32 for input variables and one for bias
    double localError, globalError;
    int i, p, iteration, output;

    weights[ 0] = randomNumber(0,1);// w1
    weights[ 1] = randomNumber(0,1);// w2
    weights[ 2] = randomNumber(0,1);// w3
    weights[ 3] = randomNumber(0,1);// w4
    weights[ 4] = randomNumber(0,1);// w5
    weights[ 5] = randomNumber(0,1);// w6
    weights[ 6] = randomNumber(0,1);// w7
    weights[ 7] = randomNumber(0,1);// w8
    weights[ 8] = randomNumber(0,1);// w9
    weights[ 9] = randomNumber(0,1);// w10
    weights[10] = randomNumber(0,1);// w11
    weights[11] = randomNumber(0,1);// w12
    weights[12] = randomNumber(0,1);// w13
    weights[13] = randomNumber(0,1);// w14
    weights[14] = randomNumber(0,1);// w15
    weights[15] = randomNumber(0,1);// w16
    weights[16] = randomNumber(0,1);// w17
    weights[17] = randomNumber(0,1);// w18
    weights[18] = randomNumber(0,1);// w19
    weights[19] = randomNumber(0,1);// w20
    weights[20] = randomNumber(0,1);// w21
    weights[21] = randomNumber(0,1);// w22
    weights[22] = randomNumber(0,1);// w23
    weights[23] = randomNumber(0,1);// w24
    weights[24] = randomNumber(0,1);// w25
    weights[25] = randomNumber(0,1);// w26
    weights[26] = randomNumber(0,1);// w27
    weights[27] = randomNumber(0,1);// w28
    weights[28] = randomNumber(0,1);// w29
    weights[29] = randomNumber(0,1);// w30
    weights[30] = randomNumber(0,1);// w31
    weights[31] = randomNumber(0,1);// this is the bias



    iteration = 0;
    do {
        iteration++;
        globalError = 0;
        //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
        for (p = 0; p < NUM_INSTANCES; p++) 
        {
            // calculate predicted class
            output = calculateOutput(theta,
                                 weights, 
                                 a00[p], 
                                 a01[p], 
                                 a02[p],
                                 a03[p],
                                 a04[p],
                                 a05[p],
                                 a06[p],
                                 a07[p],
                                 a08[p],
                                 a09[p],
                                 a10[p],
                                 a11[p],
                                 a12[p],
                                 a13[p],
                                 a14[p],
                                 a15[p],
                                 a16[p],
                                 a17[p],
                                 a18[p],
                                 a19[p],
                                 a20[p],
                                 a21[p],
                                 a22[p],
                                 a23[p],
                                 a24[p],
                                 a25[p],
                                 a26[p],
                                 a27[p],
                                 a28[p],
                                 a29[p],
                                 a30[p]);
        // difference between predicted and actual class values
            localError = outputs[p] - output;
            //update weights and bias
            weights[ 0] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a00[p];
            weights[ 1] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a01[p];
            weights[ 2] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a02[p];
            weights[ 3] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a03[p];
            weights[ 4] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a04[p];
            weights[ 5] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a05[p];
            weights[ 6] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a06[p];
            weights[ 7] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a07[p];
            weights[ 8] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a08[p];
            weights[ 9] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a09[p];
            weights[10] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a10[p];
            weights[11] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a11[p];
            weights[12] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a12[p];
            weights[13] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a13[p];
            weights[14] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a14[p];
            weights[15] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a15[p];
            weights[16] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a16[p];
            weights[17] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a17[p];
            weights[18] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a18[p];
            weights[19] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a19[p];
            weights[20] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a20[p];
            weights[21] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a21[p];
            weights[22] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a22[p];
            weights[23] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a23[p];
            weights[24] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a24[p];
            weights[25] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a25[p];
            weights[26] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a26[p];
            weights[27] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a27[p];
            weights[28] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a28[p];
            weights[29] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a29[p];
            weights[30] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a30[p];
            weights[31] += LEARNING_RATE * localError;



            //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
            globalError += (localError*localError);
        }

     /* Root Mean Squared Error */
     System.out.println("Iteration "+iteration+" : RMSE = "+Math.sqrt(globalError/NUM_INSTANCES));
    } 
    while (globalError != 0 && iteration <= MAX_ITER);

    System.out.println("\n=======\nDecision boundary equation:");

    System.out.println(
         " a00 *" + 
         weights[ 0] + 
         " a01 *" + 
         weights[ 1] + 
         " a02 *" + 
         weights[ 2] + 
         " a03 *" + 
         weights[ 3] + 
         " a04 *" + 
         weights[ 4] + 
         " a05 *" + 
         weights[ 5] + 
         " a06 *" + 
         weights[ 6] + 
         " a07 *" + 
         weights[ 7] + 
         " a08 *" + 
         weights[ 8] + 
         " a09 *" + 
         weights[ 9] + 
         " a10 *" + 
         weights[10] + 
         " a11 *" + 
         weights[11] + 
         " a12 *" + 
         weights[12] + 
         " a13 *" + 
         weights[13] + 
         " a14 *" + 
         weights[14] + 
         " a15 *" + 
         weights[15] + 
         " a16 *" + 
         weights[16] + 
         " a17 *" + 
         weights[17] + 
         " a18 *" +
         weights[18] + 
         " a19 *" + 
         weights[19] + 
         " a20 *" + 
         weights[20] + 
         " a21 *" + 
         weights[21] + 
         " a22 *" + 
         weights[22] + 
         " a23 *" + 
         weights[23] + 
         " a24 *" + 
         weights[24] + 
         " a25 *" +
         weights[25] + 
         " a26 *" + 
         weights[26] + 
         " a27 *" + 
         weights[27] + 
         " a28 *" + 
         weights[28] + 
         " a29 *" + 
         weights[29] + 
         " a30 *" +
         weights[30] +
         " bias: " +
         weights[31]);




    //2d array for features
    int x_TEST = 0;
    int[][] feature_matrix_TEST = new int[ test_perceptron_input.size() ][ GLOBO_DICT.size() ];

    for(Entry<File, int[]> entry : test_perceptron_input.entrySet())
    {
        int[] container =entry.getValue();

        for(int jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++)
        {
            feature_matrix_TEST[x_TEST][jj] = container[jj];

        }
            x_TEST++;
    }



    //three variables (features) they enumerate by
    //features, xyz, i also do that
    double[] z00 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z01 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z02 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];    
    double[] z03 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z04 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z05 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z06 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z07 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z08 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z09 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z10 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z11 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z12 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z13 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z14 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z15 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z16 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z17 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z18 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z19 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z20 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z21 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z22 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z23 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z24 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z25 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z26 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z27 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z28 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z29 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];
    double[] z30 = new double [NUM_INSTANCES];




 for(int g = 0; g < NUM_INSTANCES; g++)
 {
     z00[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 0];
     z01[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 1];
     z02[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 2];
     z03[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 3];
     z04[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 4];
     z05[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 5];
     z06[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 6];
     z07[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 7];
     z08[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 8];
     z09[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][ 9];
     z10[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][10];
     z11[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][11];
     z12[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][12];
     z13[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][13];
     z14[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][14];
     z15[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][15];
     z16[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][16];
     z17[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][17];
     z18[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][18];
     z19[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][19];
     z20[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][20];
     z21[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][21];
     z22[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][22];
     z23[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][23];
     z24[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][24];
     z25[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][25];
     z26[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][26];
     z27[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][27];
     z28[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][28];
     z29[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][29];
     z30[g] = feature_matrix_TEST[g][30];
 }




  int output_TEST;
  // calculate predicted class TEST
  output_TEST = calculateOutput(theta,
                         weights, 
                         z00[2], 
                         z01[2], 
                         z02[2],
                         z03[2],
                         z04[2],
                         z05[2],
                         z06[2],
                         z07[2],
                         z08[2],
                         z09[2],
                         z10[2],
                         z11[2],
                         z12[2],
                         z13[2],
                         z14[2],
                         z15[2],
                         z16[2],
                         z17[2],
                         z18[2],
                         z19[2],
                         z20[2],
                         z21[2],
                         z22[2],
                         z23[2],
                         z24[2],
                         z25[2],
                         z26[2],
                         z27[2],
                         z28[2],
                         z29[2],
                         z30[2]);



  System.out.println("\n=======\nTEST Point:");



  System.out.println(
                     "z00[0]:" + z00[0] + 
                     "z01[0]:" + z01[0] +  
                     "z02[0]:" + z02[0] + 
                     "z03[0]:" + z03[0] + 
                     "z04[0]:" + z04[0] + 
                     "z05[0]:" + z05[0] + 
                     "z06[0]:" + z06[0] + 
                     "z07[0]:" + z07[0] + 
                     "z08[0]:" + z08[0] + 
                     "z09[0]:" + z09[0] + 
                     "z10[0]:" + z10[0] + 
                     "z11[0]:" + z11[0] + 
                     "z12[0]:" + z12[0] + 
                     "z13[0]:" + z13[0] + 
                     "z14[0]:" + z14[0] + 
                     "z15[0]:" + z15[0] + 
                     "z16[0]:" + z16[0] + 
                     "z17[0]:" + z17[0] + 
                     "z18[0]:" + z18[0] + 
                     "z19[0]:" + z19[0] + 
                     "z20[0]:" + z20[0] + 
                     "z21[0]:" + z21[0] + 
                     "z22[0]:" + z22[0] + 
                     "z23[0]:" + z23[0] + 
                     "z24[0]:" + z24[0] + 
                     "z25[0]:" + z25[0] + 
                     "z26[0]:" + z26[0] + 
                     "z27[0]:" + z27[0] + 
                     "z28[0]:" + z28[0] + 
                     "z29[0]:" + z29[0] + 
                     "z30[0]:" + z30[0]
                    );


      System.out.println("class = "+output_TEST);
    }
  //end main  

 /**
  * returns a random double value within a given range
  * @param min the minimum value of the required range (int)
  * @param max the maximum value of the required range (int)
  * @return a random double value between min and max
  */ 
 public static double randomNumber(int min , int max) {
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
     double d = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
     String s = df.format(d);
     double x = Double.parseDouble(s);
     return x;
 }

 /**
  * returns either 1 or 0 using a threshold function
  * theta is 0range
  * @param theta an integer value for the threshold
  * @param weights[] the array of weights
  * @param x the x input value
  * @param y the y input value
  * @param z the z input value
  * @return 1 or 0
  */ 
 static int calculateOutput(int theta, 
                        double weights[], 
                        double a00, 
                        double a01,
                        double a02,
                        double a03,
                        double a04,
                        double a05,
                        double a06,
                        double a07,
                        double a08,
                        double a09,
                        double a10,
                        double a11,
                        double a12,
                        double a13,
                        double a14,
                        double a15,
                        double a16,
                        double a17,
                        double a18,
                        double a19,
                        double a20,
                        double a21,
                        double a22,
                        double a23,
                        double a24,
                        double a25,
                        double a26,
                        double a27,
                        double a28,
                        double a29,
                        double a30)
 {
    double sum = a00 * 
             weights[ 0] + 
             a01 * 
             weights[ 1] + 
             a02 * 
             weights[ 2] + 
             a03 * 
             weights[ 3] + 
             a04 * 
             weights[ 4] + 
             a05 * 
             weights[ 5] + 
             a06 * 
             weights[ 6] + 
             a07 * 
             weights[ 7] + 
             a08 * 
             weights[ 8] + 
             a09 * 
             weights[ 9] + 
             a10 * 
             weights[10] + 
             a11 * 
             weights[11] + 
             a12 * 
             weights[12] + 
             a13 * 
             weights[13] + 
             a14 * 
             weights[14] + 
             a15 * 
             weights[15] + 
             a16 * 
             weights[16] + 
             a17 * 
             weights[17] + 
             a18 * 
             weights[18] + 
             a19 * 
             weights[19] + 
             a20 * 
             weights[20] + 
             a21 * 
             weights[21] + 
             a22 * 
             weights[22] + 
             a23 * 
             weights[23] + 
             a24 * 
             weights[24] + 
             a25 *
             weights[25] + 
             a26 * 
             weights[26] + 
             a27 * 
             weights[27] + 
             a28 * 
             weights[28] + 
             a29 * 
             weights[29] + 
             a30 *
             weights[30] +  
             weights[31];

    return (sum >= theta) ? 1 : 0;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general your comments say *what* the code does. I don't recommend commenting like that, because sooner or later they will get out of date. It is better to say why things are implemented the way they are (and just don't comment when it is obvious).

You can remove the `SurpressWarning` annotations in `create_file_dict` by properly using the generics:

```
public static void create_file_dict( File file, String[] words, Map<File, ArrayList<String> > fileDict ) throws IOException
{   
    if (!fileDict.containsKey(file))
    {
        ArrayList<String> document_words = new ArrayList<String>();
        //          ^--see the generic parameter in the type

        String word;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
        {
            word = words[i];
            document_words.add(word);
        }
        fileDict.put(file, document_words);
    }
}
```

in `perceptron_data_struc_generateur`:

```
int[] cross_czech = new int[GLOBO_DICT_list.size()];
//initialize to zero
Arrays.fill(cross_czech, 0);
```

an int array is always initialized to 0 so the fill is superfluous.